# How to add secret to production value in secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, secret-key

I'm trying to run my rails in development mode but I'm greeted by this:

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`
```

I did a `rake secret` and added it to my `secrets.yml`

```
production:
  secret_key_base: 9c9fc2f9a0a212bb2bc5be64ec3bb722fc5ae01d79c1ed181f1b3a8e858c25f076e7845b67f75ab658947557d81c7fc08ba5bddf20860ec5d681b701be05***
```

Which results in this message in the browser.

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

So how do I correctly add a secret to my `secrets.yml` ?

**Update**

I've created a new secret using `rake secret`. Then added it to `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=` and ran it. Now when I do `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` I get the secret I just added. When I visit my localhost I get the `We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.` message.

This is my `secrets.yml`

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 89dacb16fd905ff4c6352ac93f4676a5dd6e***93edce9a5be796712d54b57b91e1335598fd73e3998fddbbdeaf3ee7f65157f2fb01ce1bea5658aa7bf745d1f

test:
  secret_key_base: cf351585b2cb43459f5a073cbfd885b3dd2af44124f13a85552***78c1cf06625c121cd3b7857f86e7fe2ba11180066753142143231c79c513e71e20372a0462

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

**Update 2**

This is shown in my Rails log when I visit the localhost:

```
I, [2014-11-02T16:24:57.655671 #13782]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-02 16:24:57 +0100
I, [2014-11-02T16:24:57.670779 #13782]  INFO -- : Processing by MoviesController#index as HTML
I, [2014-11-02T16:24:57.694266 #13782]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms
F, [2014-11-02T16:24:57.697056 #13782] FATAL -- : 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:18:in `current_user'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:26:in `logged_in?'
  app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

Hm, I think I need to create my database in production.

Running `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:schema:load` now lets me visit my website, allthough there's no styling etc.

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904949/rails-app-not-serving-assets-in-production-environment) adresses the problem of the no styling. I can now visit and use my App in development on my localhost. Now see if the deployed version works a bit better.

Comment: Is this an upgraded or fresh initialization of rails 4 project?

Comment: It's a fresh 4.1 project. If found `rhc set-env SECRET_KEY_BASE=key`. I've just installed the RHC gem and made a account (which is needed to run the command). I wonder if this would do anything...

Comment: If you have an environment variable, you could reference that in your `config/secrets.yml`.  See linked: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-secrets-yml

Comment: How do I see if I have an `environment variable`?

Comment: On your terminal prompt, run `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE`, that should show you the value if it's set.

Comment: Running `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` doesn't show me anything. So the problem is that my secrets.yml is looking for a variable called `$secret_key_base`. But that doesn't excist. So I have to add on to my `environment variable` ?

Comment: I thought you already had the environment variable.  You can test that using `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=<key>`.  Replace `<key>` with your key.  Try this first and could you also post your full `secrets.yml` as is, please update your question to add this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll create an answer using the information.

Comment: Like must be renamed to secrets.yml.erb