# Precompiling assets throws "Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ sys_fail2" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have deployed my rails application on the server but it is showing me an error when i try to precompile the assets also, whenever I try to run my server in production environment it throws **`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):`** error everytime. As this Question suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904949/rails-app-not-serving-assets-in-production-environment) to precomplie your assets. but i am still getting this error:

```
deploy@TTP:/srv/ttp$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    I, [2015-06-17T07:40:19.366868 #14706]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/ttp/public/assets/application-b70462741c5220649c0fae6b371f8bb0db1f69df9980817ca94517d13ec3e90e.js
    I, [2015-06-17T07:40:27.543196 #14706]  INFO -- : Writing /srv/ttp/public/assets/application-8fad86d02acda5dc8d383ef570b85dc9991784b53d994dc532ed69632be450db.css
    rake aborted!
    Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ sys_fail2 - (/srv/ttp/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-81cc84ad6ecbcbede263dab4150a3105.json.11450760.14706.293714, /srv/ttp/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-81cc84ad6ecbcbede263dab4150a3105.json)
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.0.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:277:in `atomic_write'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.0.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:261:in `save'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.0.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:183:in `compile'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.0.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
    Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

**log/production.log**

```
I, [2015-05-12T12:36:11.882313 #26372]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 1.22.20.40 at 2015-05-12 12:36:11 -0400
I, [2015-05-12T12:36:11.895927 #26372]  INFO -- : Processing by RecordsController#index as HTML
I, [2015-05-12T12:36:11.908520 #26372]  INFO -- :   Rendered records/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
I, [2015-05-12T12:36:11.926940 #26372]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 28.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
I, [2015-05-12T12:36:12.307845 #26372]  INFO -- : Started GET "/stylesheets/application.css" for 1.22.20.40 at 2015-05-12 12:36:12 -0400
F, [2015-05-12T12:36:12.309134 #26372] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
  puma (2.11.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call'
  puma (2.11.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Probably user doesn't have rights to write to /srv/ttp/public/assets/ did you check it?

Comment: @Fenec Even after changing everything to 777, it says ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):

Comment: Did you run precompile again after setting everything to 777?

Comment: @jfornoff Yes, i did compiled and it happened successfully.

Comment: I'm not sure how lookup of digested precompiled assets exactly works, but  I could imagine that it would make sense to restart the servers as well, in case you have not done that yet.

Comment: @jfornoff It seems to be working now, after i remove my complete repository and cloned it again, then ran assets:precompile and it worked this time..It it so stupid that for some reason things doesnt work and after sometimes they starts working again.

Comment: Definitely hard to figure out at times. Glad you made it work though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your compiled assert is saved here

`/assets/application-b70462741c5220649c0fae6b371f8bb0db1f69df9980817ca94517d13ec3e90e.js`

but your client tries to get

`/stylesheets/application.css`

You should change the path of the CSS assert on your client.
if you confuse, post your template where you set the CSS file.

Comment: if you notice my last comment, I got it working with little help.

Comment: I dont know but removing everything, then changing my folder rights to 777 and then asset compilation did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this exact same error by removing all directories within my releases/ directory and running cap deploy again.

Can't explain, but I thought this might help someone!